# how to get or set the the item index of a textbox in a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I've searched and searched and searched but I can't seem to find an answer to what I (may mistakenly) believe to be a very simple issue.

I have listview which the user can add items into, using a button and an OpenFileDialog. This works.

The Problem is as follows:

One column in the listview comprises of a textbox. I would like the user will be able to add (numeric) value to the textbox and the value will be associated with the item (in that row). I've created a textbox in one of the columns, and after very extensive search I added the LostFocus option in order to get it's value (i.e - the textbox value). The problem now is that the index of the selecteditem in the listview is not always set (maybe because the item is chosen before the lostfocus invokes). This results in selectedindex being -1, so i don't know which item should be associated with the text from the textbox.

I've also tried using the mouse click events which will assist me in choosing the right item, but that was not fruitful as well.

I am using **listview** and **wpf** so many solutions I came across seem to be irrelevant. In addition, I am very new to wpf (and an amateur programmer) so I'm having trouble understanding the complex solutions... however, I believe that this issue might not be as complex as it seems.

please please help.

this is my code:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Width="30" Header="Num" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Num}" />
        <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
        <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="FromPage">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txt_TBFromPage" LostFocus="txt_FromPage_LostFocus" Text="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=txtValue}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

and this is the c# part:

```
private void txt_FromPage_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    int Index = MyListView.SelectedIndex;

    Index = MyListView.Items.IndexOf(MyListView.SelectedItem);

    try {
        //Get cell value by using sender Object
        string TextValue = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)sender).Text;

        MyItem item = (MyItem)MyListView.Items[Index];
        item.FromPage = TextValue;

    }

    catch (Exception) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could add the following:

.cs

```
    private void txt_TBFromPage_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyListView.SelectedItem = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
    }
```

.xaml

```
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_TBFromPage" GotFocus="txt_TBFromPage_GotFocus"  LostFocus="txt_TBFromPage_LostFocus"  Text="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=txtValue}" />
```

fits your needs?